# Trying to select and print the submitted answer in my dropdown

Tags: php, html

I have this small Capital quiz i have to make for a school project, first, i had to import all options using a php array, which i did as you can see in the code. i've made sure you could choose every capital using a foreach loop in the  tag. The problem is, i dont know how to save the submitted answer. and print it under the button after it has been submitted. If you have an idea, help would be appreciated. Sorry for any grammar mistakes. English isn't my first language.

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
    <body>
      <?php $capital = array(
      "Italy"=>"Rome", "Luxembourg"=>"Luxembourg", "Belgium"=> "Brussels", "Denmark"=>"Copenhagen",
      "Finland"=>"Helsinki", "France" => "Paris", "Slovakia"=>"Bratislava", "Slovenia"=>"Ljubljana",
      "Germany" => "Berlin", "Greece" => "Athens", "Ireland"=>"Dublin", "Netherlands"=>"Amsterdam",
      "Portugal"=>"Lisbon", "Spain"=>"Madrid", "Sweden"=>"Stockholm", "United Kingdom"=>"London",
      "Cyprus"=>"Nicosia", "Lithuania"=>"Vilnius", "Czech Republic"=>"Prague", "Estonia"=>"Tallin",
      "Hungary"=>"Budapest", "Latvia"=>"Riga", "Malta"=>"Valetta", "Austria" => "Vienna",
      "Poland"=>"Warsaw") ;
      $l = array_rand($capital);
      $h = $capital[$l]; 
      echo "What is the capital of ".$l."?";
      ?>
      <br><br>
      <form method="POST">
        <select name="cap">
          <?php
          foreach ($capital as $country => $city) {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $city ?>" ><?php echo $city ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
      <br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Check Answer!">
      <br><br>
    </form>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
      $getCapital=$_POST[$capital];
      echo "Your answer was ".$getCapital;
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are not calling the correct "POST"

Comment: Vote to close as typo

Answer (score 0):

Because you gave the field on the form the name `cap` in this line

```
<select name="cap">
```

To access the value the user selected in that select dropdown is

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo "Your answer was ".$_POST['cap'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **`$getCapital=$_POST[$capital]`** is wrong

**Use It:-**

```
$getCapital=$_POST['cap'];
```

Comment: I changed it, still doesnt seem to fix the problem.

Comment: @ArjenBos please check my answer for a further edit that needs to be made and advice on how to spot this sort of thing in future scripts

Comment: Check My New Answer !

Answer (score 0):

The `$_POST` in your code is whats known in PHP as a [superglobal](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) ([docs on $_POST](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)) and contains the data of any request sent to this script using the HTTP POST method.

The first step is to do some simple debugging and check the contents of the `$_POST` superglobal being passed to this script when your form is submitted (a `<form>` without an `action` attribute will send it's data back to the same script), you can do this by (`var_dump()`ing) the contents of `$_POST` at the top of your script:

```php
<?php var_dump($_POST) ?>
```

As you might be able to tell from looking at the post data available there are two bugs with your current code:

1: `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` is looking for a value with the key `submit` in `$_POST` which doesn't exist, this should be `if(isset($_POST['cap'])){`

2: `$getCapital=$_POST[$capital];` is looking for a value in `$_POST` based on the contents of another variable; `$capital` which happens to be an array in your code and also isn't present in the data submitted, this should be changed to `$getCapital=$_POST['cap'];`

Answer (score 0):

**`Use It :-`**

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
    <body>
      <?php $capital = array(
      "Italy"=>"Rome", "Luxembourg"=>"Luxembourg", "Belgium"=> "Brussels", "Denmark"=>"Copenhagen",
      "Finland"=>"Helsinki", "France" => "Paris", "Slovakia"=>"Bratislava", "Slovenia"=>"Ljubljana",
      "Germany" => "Berlin", "Greece" => "Athens", "Ireland"=>"Dublin", "Netherlands"=>"Amsterdam",
      "Portugal"=>"Lisbon", "Spain"=>"Madrid", "Sweden"=>"Stockholm", "United Kingdom"=>"London",
      "Cyprus"=>"Nicosia", "Lithuania"=>"Vilnius", "Czech Republic"=>"Prague", "Estonia"=>"Tallin",
      "Hungary"=>"Budapest", "Latvia"=>"Riga", "Malta"=>"Valetta", "Austria" => "Vienna",
      "Poland"=>"Warsaw") ;
      $l = array_rand($capital);
      $h = $capital[$l]; 
      echo "What is the capital of ".$l."?";
      ?>
      <br><br>
      <form method="POST">
        <select name="cap">
          <?php
          foreach ($capital as $country => $city) {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $city ?>" ><?php echo $city ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
      <br><br>
      <input type="submit"name="sub" value="Check Answer!">
      <br><br>
    </form>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['sub'])){
      $getCapital=$_POST['cap'];
      echo "Your answer was ".$getCapital;
    }
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its better to give an explanation of the solution than simply provide the solution itself, that way the asker can learn from the experience