# I want a good answer counter on my capital quiz

Tags: php, html

im fairly new to PHP, i made a capital quiz for a school project, now i wanted to make a good answer counter aswell. it has to show how many good answers you've had in a row. and has to reset whenever you submit the wrong answer. i dont have a clue how to do this. any help would be really appreciated.

````
  <head>
  </head>
    <body>
      <?php $capital = array(
      "Italië"=>"Rome", "Luxemburg"=>"Luxemburg", "België"=> "Brussel", "Denemarken"=>"Kopenhagen",
      "Finland"=>"Helsinki", "Frankrijk" => "Parijs", "Slowakije"=>"Bratislava", "Slovenië"=>"Ljubljana",
      "Duitsland" => "Berlijn", "Griekenland" => "Athene", "Ierland"=>"Dublin", "Nederland"=>"Amsterdam",
      "Portugal"=>"Lissabon", "Spanje"=>"Madrid", "Zweden"=>"Stockholm", "Verenigd Koninkrijk"=>"Londen",
      "Cyprus"=>"Nicosia", "Litouwen"=>"Vilnius", "Tsjechië"=>"Praag", "Estland"=>"Tallinn",
      "Hongarije"=>"Budapest", "Letland"=>"Riga", "Malta"=>"Valetta", "Oostenrijk" => "Wenen",
      "Polen"=>"Warschau") ;
      asort($capital);
      $l = array_rand($capital);
      $h = $capital[$l]; 
      echo "What is the capital of ".$l."?";
      ?>
      <br><br>
      <form method="POST">
        <select name="cap">
          <option selected disabled>Choose your capital: <option>
          <?php
          foreach ($capital as $country => $city) {
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $city ?>" ><?php echo $city ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        </select>
      <br><br>
      <input type="hidden" name="juisteland" value="<?php echo $l ?>">
      <input type="submit"name="sub" value="Check Answer!">
      <br><br>
    </form>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['cap'])){
      $getCountry=$_POST['juisteland'];
      $getCapital=$_POST['cap'];
      if($getCapital == $capital[$getCountry]){
        echo "The capital of ".$getCountry." is ". $getCapital.", this is correct.";
      }
      if($getCapital != $capital[$getCountry]){
        echo "Sorry, the capital of  ".$getCountry." is not ". $getCapital.", but ".$capital[$getCountry];
    }

    }
?>
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: [Didn't you ask this already?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61015086/1415724)

Comment: No, its kind of a followup.

Comment: On the first topic i had a problem with making the quiz work. Now im looking to add a good answer count

Answer (score 1):

Declare a variable at the beginning `$count=0`, and increment/decrement it in your code as follows:

```
if($getCapital == $capital[$getCountry]){
        echo "The capital of ".$getCountry." is ". $getCapital.", this is correct.";
        $count++;
}else{
        echo "Sorry, the capital of  ".$getCountry." is not ". $getCapital.", but ".$capital[$getCountry];
        $count = 0;
}
```